# Concatenate variable name with variable value Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a flexible amount of titles, aka title1, title2, title3 etc. How can i create a dynamic variable that gives me the value of that field?

```
function getTitle(i){
    var myScope={}
    myScope["title"+i]="title"+i // should i use this in any way, and how?

    var output = props.attributes.title1 // This works, but it is static. Instead the 1, add the value of i here like:
    var output = props.attributes.title+i
    return output
}
```

I would like to concatenate the value of i to the word 'title'. So it becomes title1 or title2 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it dynamic like this

```js
var output = props.attributes[`title${i}`];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right you can use template literals.

```js
function getTitle(i) {
  let title = 'myTitle'

  let output = `${title} ${i}`
  console.log(output)
  return output
}

getTitle('concated')
```